# CSS is not working on mozilla firefox browser

Tags: css, firefox

Here is my CSS code:

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus::-moz-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
```

My CSS is not working on Mozilla Firefox. Please let me know what is wrong in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/), the correct selector is:

```
::-moz-placeholder /* Firefox v19+ */
:-moz-placeholder  /* Firefox v18- */
```

<sup>(Because it seems you're using CSS3 selectors, you can just use the former)</sup>

You probably got this confused because Webkit has its own vendor prefix of `-webkit-input-`, but Firefox only has `-moz-` (without the `input`).

Comment: @SandeepKumar If my answer works for you, please accept it (press the green check mark next to it) to show the SO community it is the right answer. Thanks!